# How to do bulk insert in Mysql with Guid primary key autoincrement?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, bulkinsert

I need to Insert a few records to my Mysql table. I have text document with values. I have 7 columns in my content record. be that as it may, in my table i have 8 columns. i.e., i have Guid primary key section. I have made that table as of now. How might i insert  those values to mysql table since I don't have guid? Any help would be truly valued.

Here is my text file:
I want to insert zip code,city and so.. with comma..

00501,+40.922326,-072.637078,HOLTSVILLE,NY,SUFFOLK,UNIQUE
00544,+40.922326,-072.637078,HOLTSVILLE,NY,SUFFOLK,UNIQUE

etc..

I have tried this query. but its not working.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'F:/../ZIP_CODES.txt'
INTO TABLE dbo.mastertable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

it says, row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns. Please help.

Comment: Can You show me sample data in text file.

Comment: 00501,+40.922326,-072.637078,HOLTSVILLE,NY,SUFFOLK,UNIQUE

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'F:/../ZIP_CODES.txt' 
        INTO TABLE dbo.mastertable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Comment: it inserted all the values buddy. but it started from column 1. it skips last column. but i want to insert Guid for my first column.